# Batch file: get absolute path of parent directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I recently came across to a situation where need to fetch parent directory of currently being executed batch file. Searched for the solution on google and stackoverflow but could find a clean and easy solution.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for.

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("%~dp0\.") do echo "%%~dpnxa"
for %%a in ("%~dp0\.") do for %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do echo "%%~dpnxb"
pause
```